# Where can I find Hebrew and Greek Bible texts interlined with Strong's numbers in plain text or JSON format?

Tags: data-request, research, json, religion, txt

Example in Hebrew:

```
Gen 1:1  בראשׁיתH7225 בראH1254 אלהיםH430 אתH853 השׁמיםH8064 ואתH853 הארץ׃H776
```

Example in Greek:

```
Mat 1:1  βιβλοςG976 γενεσεωςG1078 ιησουG2424 χριστουG5547 υιουG5207 δαβιδG1138 υιουG5207 αβρααμG11
```

Comment: http://biblehub.com/interlinear/genesis/1.htm and http://biblehub.com/interlinear/matthew/1.htm look scrapable…

Comment: Did you ever end up scraping this or getting it some other way?